# iptables infographic

Tags: iptables, firewall

Is there an infographic somewhere that describes the logical flow of `iptables`? Specifically, I'm looking for something that diagrams which point in the process `ip_conntrack` applies.

Comment: [Does one of these ring a bell](https://encrypted.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=netfilter+diagram|schema)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This netfilter diagram](http://jengelh.medozas.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png) ([svg](http://inai.de/images/nf-packet-flow.svg)) seems to fit.

Comment: ROCKIN!! That was exactly the link I was looking for!!

Comment: Hey, thats kinda nifty. Another reference doc to print out and hang on the cube wall :-)

Comment: By the way how did you find it what were the search terms? My google-fu apparently was not enough to get it done.

Comment: They were [netfilter diagram|schema]. I mentioned it in a comment on your post.